# How to Save android app user data to server

Tags: android, database, android-studio, server

Currently I am working on one android app which takes user's info and let them register for the app.

But I am having problem while connecting my backend with my app.

In order to save the data I use server host which I don't know how to implement for android users.

Help me with this so that I can start building my apps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending basic user info, maybe you can publish a rest webservice on the server and consume it from android app. im using retrofit right now to consume rest webservices from android and is very easy to use.

Comment: just I am using for learning purpose ,
so does it require some money or is it free...?
help please

Comment: Free. It's licence under Apache License, Version 2.0. For info you can check at http://square.github.io/retrofit/.

Comment: You welcome. If you find it helpful, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: actually I was not able to upvote your answer at that time